# Jquery Issue With Form Select Drop Down Hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a drop down menu with form select options for quantity. The drop down works with Jquery hover. So, on hover of the menu icon, the drop down appears, and when you over off of it, it hides. Every time I try to change the select option, it shows the rest of the quantity. But when I hover onto a different option or off of the first select option, the entire drop down menu hides.

```
$("#navigation #seven").live({
    mouseenter:function(){
        $(this).find('ul').show();
    },
    mouseleave:function() {
        $(this).find('ul').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post some details so that we can dertermine what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

this happens because you are mouseouting the menuitem when you try to get to the select.

you must surround the menu item and the select by a container and apply hover on the div

```
<div id="hoverable">
   <menuitem />
   <select style="display:none"><option></option></select>
</div>
```

and then, apply the hover to the div

```
$('#hoverable').hover(function(){
   $(this).find('select').show();
}, function(){
   $(this).find('select').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest setting a timeout in the hover off, let's say a couple hundred ms. In your menu, set a flag true when you hover on it, and false when you hover off. So, if your menu icon's hover off sees that flag as true, it doesn't hide the drop down menu.

Example:

```
var overMenu = false;
$(menuItem).hover(
    function() {
        $(dropDownMenu).show();
    },
    function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if ( !overMenu )
                $(dropDownMenu).hide();
        }, 200);
    }
);
$(dropDownMenu).hover(
    function() { overMenu = true; },
    function() {
        overMenu = false;
        $(this).hide();
    }
};
```

Comment: Here's my code. I tried what you had, but it wasn't working. Throws errors in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
var hover_off = false;
var hover_count = 1000;

$("#navigation #seven").live("mouseover",function(){
    hover_off = false;
    $(this).find('ul').show();
});

$("#navigation #seven").live("mouseout",function(){
    hover_off = true;
    setTimeout(myMouseOut, hover_count);
});

function myMouseOut() {
    if (hover_off) {
        $("#navigation #seven").find('ul').hide();
    }
}
```